# Difference between different ways in instantiating an object in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, extends

I have the code:

```
class Father{
    String name="father";
    void f(){System.out.print("father class");}   
}

class Son extends Father{
    String name = "son";
    void f(){System.out.print("son class");}
    void f2(){}
}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Father s = new Son();
        System.out.println(s.name);//  outputs father
        s.f();// outputs "son class"
        s.f2();// s does not have f2
    }

}
```

My question is, what is the difference between doing Father s = new Father() or, Father s = new Son() or, Son s = new Son()?

As well, why does s.f2 in the example cause an error? Must Father implement f2()?

Comment: You're instantiating `s` as a more general type `Father` object even though under the hood it is really a `Son`, a specific type (subclass of) `Father`. Since the type of `s` as Java sees it is `Father`, and the `Father` class has no method `f2()`, you have an error.

Comment: It's not a more general type of object, the *object* it's still a `Son`, it's just being assigned to a *variable* of type `Father`.

Comment: P.S. I don't know the application, but doesn't it make more sense that all Fathers are Sons, but not all Sons are Fathers?

Comment: Example is wrong at general level, so hard to discuss. Son v/s Father is not inheritance. Hard to get natural understanding

Comment: @ChrisSprague So the only difference is, if Father s = new Son(), Father will still be a Father, however if Son overrides a method from Father, the method from Son would be used? Thanks for your help!

Comment: I agree the example is pretty weird, it's from a previous test for a class I'm currently taking so that might explain it, haha.

Comment: @JCB I'd suggest reading some of the more detailed answers below; they're better than the quick and dirty comment I gave trying to explain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is easier to explain with an animal example:

```
class Animal {

    void printName() {
        System.out.println("Animal");
    }
}
class Dog extends Animal{

    @Override
    void printName() {
        System.out.println("Dog");
    }
}
class Cat extends Animal{

    @Override
    void printName() {
        System.out.println("Cat");
    }

    void meow() {
        System.out.println("meow");
    }
}
```

When you extend classes, the child class can override parent's methods and can have its own methods. In my Animal example the generic Animal object can only give its name, but the Cat object can give its name and also meow. Obviously, the meow method is specific to Cat as we know that Dogs can't do meow and Animals in general.

When you do

```
Animal animal  = new Cat();
```

You actually create an instance of the Cat but use it as a general Animal. Thus, your animal instance only has methods which are available in the Animal class but the execution of the methods overridden by Cat class will be delegated to the Cat class. 
if you want to execute Cat's specific methods then you need to cast your Animal to the Cat

```
(Cat) animal.meow();
```

In your example to call f2() method you need to cast your father object to the son first

```
(Son)s.f2();
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're dealing with is reference type (variable type) and object type (what's actually being referred to). The Java compiler needs some kind of guarantee that the object being referred to can run the method you're calling. To do this, it looks to the *reference type*. When executed, the method run is that of the *object type*.

Simply put:

```
Father f = new Father(); //Treated as a Father, behaves like a Father
Son s = new Son();       //Treated as a Son, behaves like a Son
Father q = new Son();    //Treated as a Father, behaves like a Son (sounds like my own father)
```

If you *cast* q to a Son by saying `(Son)q`, it will be treated as a `Son` by the compiler, unless the object isn't *actually* a Son, in which case you'll get a `ClassCastException`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a simpler concept, since your hierarchy implies that all `Son`s are `Father`s, but not all `Father`s are `Son`s (which ain't quite true).

Let's take the abstract class `Number` and any of its children - for brevity, we can use `Integer`, `Float` and `BigInteger`.

Suppose we declare this:

```
Number num = Float.NaN;
```

We now have a `Float` instance which is referenced by a `Float`.  We can do anything we want to that instance, but **only in the context of a `Number`**.

There's a useful method for `Float` called `isNan` which would allow us to see if our float actually *is* a number.  In the context of `Number`...that method doesn't exist.

There are advantages to doing it like this - if you don't need the specificity of the child reference, you can refer to everything by its parent class (or interface).  This also uncouples you from the child's API should you want to be uncoupled from it (see [developing to an interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html)).

Answer (score 0):

s.f2() is the syntax error because you told JVM that s is Father, not Son.

In the code, it can't find f2 method in Father class

```
class Father{
    String name="father";
    void f(){System.out.print("father class");}   
}
```

But it doesn't mean the code is wrong, just the JVM doesn't like it.

if you change s.f2() to

```
(Son)s.f2();
```

It will works

Answer (score 0):

OK I see where is the confusion here.

**In java you can override methods but not class variables**

keep that rule in mind

So when you did

Father s = new Son();

**the object "s" is of type father**

and as we said the variables inside it wont be overwritten just the methods
So the the final result is an object that has the member variables from the Father class (the "name" variable)  and the method from son class (since father had only 1 method and son overridden it).

**and for why the f2 does not work**

it is because the object "s" is of type Father not son (it is father object that has 1 method of it overwritten by son class  other than that it will keep be father object) and Father does not have f2 method thats why you get the compile error